# MVC 6 change return content-type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I seem to be unable to change the return content-type of my controller-method in the new Asp.net MVC 6.

I tried various variations on:

```
Context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "text/x-vcard");
```

In the old WebApi days I could use this, and change the formatter:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data, JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType);
```

Could I do something similar in MVC 6?

Comment: If you format something in Json, why would you want to change the content-type?

Comment: Json is an example of a MediaTypeFormatter. I want to use text/x-vcard. But I don't see how I can change the MediaTypeFormatter for one method, or change the content-type header

Comment: Why dont you use content negotiation? If the user requests a response of type `text/x-vcard`, it will automatically use that response type, given that you have a converter for that. Otherwise it will default to json

Comment: The client is the browser in this case. I have no control over it.

Comment: @mhtsbt Did you try to set `Response.ContentType` property?

Comment: Yes, but probably like Dominik said, I need a custom formatter first. Will test that asap and let my results know.

Comment: @mhtsbt did you manage to create a custom formatter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that by setting the `Produces("ResultType")` attribute on the controller action. For example:

```
[Produces("application/xml")]
public Object Index()
{
    return new { Id = 100 };
}
```

The `formatter` for the given result type will be used to convert the `object`, regardless of the `Accept Header`.

But you need to have a `formatter` registered for the response type. So if you want to use `"text/x-vcard"`, you'd have to create a formatter for that.

To do that you need to create a class that implements `IOutputFormatter` and register it in `Startup.cs` in the `ConfigureServices()` method like this:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new VCardFormatter());
});
```

---

Here are some **additional resources** that may help you do that:

[Content negotiation in MVC 6](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/24/content-negotiation-in-mvc-5-or-how-can-i-just-write-json.aspx)

[Formatters in ASP.NET MVC 6](http://www.strathweb.com/2014/11/formatters-asp-net-mvc-6/)

Comment: What if I want to return a problem as described by RFC 7807, where the media type only changes to `application/problem+json` if I actually return a problem, and otherwise should stay at `application/json`?